# Solutions to equation $x^{\frac2 7}=16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

My son had this question on his college algebra homework.
Solve $x^\frac{2}{7}=16$.

The question doesn't specify the domain, but they have learned about complex numbers.

It's an online homework assignment, and it tells him if his answer is correct and will let him change to a different answer. The online system would not accept the answer 16384, but would only accept the answer {16384, -16384}.

R says $(-16384)^\frac{2}{7}$ is not a number (NaN).

Mathematica says $(-16384)^\frac{2}{7}=16 (-1)^\frac{2}{7}$, which begs the question: What is $(-1)^\frac{2}{7}$?

I understand that $((-16384)^2)^\frac{1}{7}=16$, but $((-16384)^\frac{1}{7})^2$ is again not a number according to R and is $16 (-1)^\frac{2}{7}$ according to Mathematica.

Finally, using Solve or Reduce in Mathematica, it says there is only one solution $x=16384$.

Comment: The equation is $\sqrt[7]{x^2}=16$, so $x^2=16^7$. Of course this has two solutions. So $x=\pm 16384$.

Comment: Hmm, if you wanted to use complex number $-1 = re^{\theta i}$ when $r=1; \theta = 2k\pi + \pi$ so $(-1)^{\frac 27} = e^{(\frac 47k\pi + \frac 27\pi)i}$ which are seven complex number so which the only real number is $e^{(\frac 47\cdot 3\pi + \frac 27\pi)i}=e^{2\pi i}= 1$.... but that's overkill.  However my point is $(-1)^{\frac 27}$ may be defined differently in different contexts.   If $(-1)^{\frac 27}$ is allowed to be anything, $1$ is its real value. R probably just doesn't allow $(neg)^x$. period.  (Because $b^x:= e^{b\ln x}$ and $\ln neg$ is undefined. But R isn't end all and be all.

Comment: In this level of algebra, you use the real root, so $(-1)^\frac27=1$. You can simply solve it as $x^2=16^7\iff \sqrt{x^2}=|x|=16^\frac72$, so $x=\pm 16384$. Another way is to notice that when raising both sides to the $\frac72$, even denominator powers are like square roots, requiring the absolute value, so we solve it by $x^\frac27=16\iff |x|=16^\frac72\implies x=\pm 16384$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different conventions at work here which lead to **different** answers.

First their is the basic algebra convention that $x^{\frac{a}{b}}$ for $\frac{a}{b}$ a fully reduced fraction should be interpreted as $(x^a)^{\frac{1}{b}}$. If you interpret it this way, then indeed $x=-16384$ and $x=16384$ are the two solutions to the equation $x^{\frac{2}{7}}=16$.

Second there is a general interpretation of $x^y$ for $x \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Write $x=r\cdot e^{i\varphi}$ in polar coordinates, with $ r > 0$ and $\varphi \in  [0, 2\pi)$, then $x^y = (r\cdot e^{i\varphi})^y = r^y \cdot e^{iy\varphi}$. This is also a complex number in polar coordinates if you interpret the $y\varphi$ modulo $2\pi$. With this interpretation there is only a single complex solution to $x^{\frac{2}{7}}=16$, namely $x=16384$, but $x=-16384$ **is not** a solution.

Answer (score 6):

By the usual conventions used in College Algebra, $x^{a/b} = (x^a)^{1/b}$ if $x$ is real and $a/b$ is a rational number in lowest terms with $a$ even.

Answer (score 2):

In analysis and calculus $b^x:= e^{x\ln b}$ and if $b \le 0$ you will get $NaN$ and that is probably what is going on with R.

But in other context if $r\in \mathbb Q$ then $b^r=b^{\frac nm}:= (b^n)^{\frac 1m}$ where $r=\frac nm$ expressed in lowest terms.  In this case if $m$ is even and $b$ is negative we are out of luck but otherwise its just fine.  So $(-1)^{\frac 27} = ((-1)^2)^{\frac 17}=1^{\frac 17} = 1$.  And that's probably what's going on everywhere else.

But...

And... just to go nuts... in complex analysis we convert a complex number $a+bi; a,b\in\mathbb R$ to form $r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta) = re^{\theta i}$ were $r= |a+bi|$ and $\theta = arg(a+bi)$.  So in that case:

$-1 = 1e^{(2\pi k +\pi) i}$ and $(-1)^{\frac 27}$ will be the seven complex numbers

$e^{\frac {4\pi k + 2\pi}7i} = \cos \frac {4\pi k + 2\pi}7 + i \sin \frac {4\pi k + 2\pi}7$ for $k = 0,$ to $6$.  Of these $7$ complex numbers the one where $k=3$ yields

$\cos\frac {12\pi + 2\pi}7 + i\sin \frac {12\pi + 2\pi}7 = \cos 2\pi + i \sin 2\pi = 1+ i\cdot 0 = 1$.

Which, lo and behold, is exactly what we wanted it to be.

Answer (score 2):

R returns NaN for complex numbers unless you specify `as.complex()` or use functions designed for complex numbers. You can use `polyroot` to find all of the roots of a polynomial. The function takes the a vector of polynomial coefficients in ascending order as the argument. In this case, you can solve $16^7-x^2 = 0$:

```
polyroot(c(16^7, 0, -1))
[1]  16384+0i -16384+0i
```

Or $x = (-1)^{2/7} \longrightarrow x^7-1=0$:

```
> polyroot(c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
[1]  0.6234898+0.7818315i -0.9009689+0.4338837i -0.2225209-0.9749279i  0.6234898-0.7818315i
[5] -0.2225209+0.9749279i -0.9009689-0.4338837i  1.0000000+0.0000000i
```

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{\frac27} =16$$

$$(x^{\frac27})^{\frac72} =x =16^{\frac72}=\pm 4^7=\pm16384 $$

That is because we can multiply the repeated exponents in this case and the $\pm$ is for the square root of 16 admitting two roots of opposite sign. As the exponent  7 is odd, negative sign carries through.

Comment: Why did you put parentheses in the first equation?

Comment: :) Did not remove them after cut, paste, edit from second line.. since removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the absolute value of both sides, you get:

$$|x|^{2/7} = 16$$
$$|x|^2 = 16^7 = 2^{28}$$
$$|x| = 2^{14} = 16384$$

But what if $x \in \mathbb{C}$?  Recall that according to [DeMoivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), that if $x$ is expressed in polar form as $x = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$, with $r = |x| \ge 0$, then:

$$x^n = r^n \left(\cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta) \right)$$

Plugging in $r = 16384$ and $n = \frac{2}{7}$ gives:

$$x^{2/7} = 16384^{2/7} \left(\cos(\frac{2\theta}{7}) + i\sin(\frac{2\theta}{7}) \right) = 16$$
$$16 \left(\cos(\frac{2\theta}{7}) + i\sin(\frac{2\theta}{7}) \right) = 16$$
$$\cos(\frac{2\theta}{7}) + i\sin(\frac{2\theta}{7}) = 1$$
$$\frac{2\theta}{7} = 2\pi k, k \in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\theta = 7\pi k, k \in\mathbb{Z}$$

Thus:

$$x \in \{ 16384\left(\cos(7\pi k) + i \sin(7\pi k) \right) : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

But $\sin$ is 0 for any integer multiple of $\pi$, and $\cos(7\pi k)$ must be either $1$ (if $k$ is even, and thus $7k$ is even), or $-1$ (if $k$ is odd, and thus $7k$ is odd).  Thus,

$$x = \pm 16384$$